# Проблема с flex box

Tags: flexbox

У меня такая проблема, что когда задаю display flex родительскому блоку, то 2 маленьких блока не складываются в один столбик, а просто выстраиваются в линию. Есть идеи как это исправить?
[image: drop меню]

```css
.drop {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.drop__h3 {
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
}
.drop__link {
    color: #646464;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.drop__menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.drop__flex {
    width: 235px;
    margin-right: 46px;
}
.drop__flex:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
                <div class="drop">
                    <div class="drop__flex">
                        <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                        <ul class="drop__menu">
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Jackets/Coats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Blazers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Denim</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Leggings/Pants</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Skirts/Shorts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop__flex">
                        <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                        <ul class="drop__menu">
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop__flex">
                        <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                        <ul class="drop__menu">
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="drop__flex">
                        <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                        <ul class="drop__menu">
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Jackets/Coats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Blazers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Denim</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Leggings/Pants</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Skirts/Shorts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если количество элементов не будет меняться, то можно маленькие блоки обернуть в div к примеру.

```
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop__flex">
                <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                <ul class="drop__menu">
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Jackets/Coats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Blazers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Denim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Leggings/Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Skirts/Shorts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="drop__flex">
                <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                <ul class="drop__menu">
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="drop__flex">
                <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                <ul class="drop__menu">
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop__flex">
                <h3 class="drop__h3">Women</h3>
                <ul class="drop__menu">
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Dresses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Sweaters/Knits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Jackets/Coats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Blazers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Denim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Leggings/Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Skirts/Shorts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="drop__link">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: В ещё один поверх drop__flex?

Comment: 2 маленьких блока обернуть в один div

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо)